# How to parse this output and put it into an array?

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

i have expect script whose output looks like :

I would like to extract all words like Gi/02/12 etc in an array or a list.

```
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
121  Voice_C-LAN                      active    Gi1/0/12, Gi1/0/13, Gi1/0/14, Gi1/0/15, Gi1/0/16, Gi1/0/17, Gi1/0/18, Gi1/0/19, Gi1/0/20, Gi1/0/21, Gi1/0/22
                                                Gi1/0/23, Fa2/0/13, Fa2/0/14, Fa2/0/15, Fa2/0/16, Fa2/0/17, Fa2/0/18, Fa2/0/19, Fa2/0/20, Fa2/0/21, Fa2/0/22
                                                Fa2/0/23, Fa2/0/24, Gi2/0/1

VLAN Type  SAID       MTU   Parent RingNo BridgeNo Stp  BrdgMode Trans1 Trans2
```

Comment: Another approach, in case you're not aware of it, is—assuming this is coming from a switch or similar—to use the SNMP command-line tools. May be easier, depending on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: right i am am completely unaware of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `grep -o` with this minimal pattern:

```
grep -o '..././..' file
```